# PDO::FETCH_CLASS with multiple classes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to turn an query result into classes.

```
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'myclass', array());
```

This works quite well however the class name `myclass` depends on the column values.

Is it possible to fetch each row and turn it into a different class depending on the rows values?

---

User example:

```
ID # name # age
1  # jon  # 12
2  # sue  # 23
3  # tom  # 24
```

I want to have all users with an age less then 21 to be instances of the class `child`.
Rows with age of 21 and above should be instances of the class `adult`.

So "jon" should be an instance of `child`.
"sue" and "tom" should be instances of `adult`.

Comment: So one database query should return multiple types?

Comment: Yes it has to be one query and I can't change it.

Comment: What prevents you, let's say, to overload an array with the returned data instead? Not that I say you should do it, but I'd like to understand the reason.

Comment: It's only a bug in so I don't want to change the whole system to fix the bug.

Comment: I think which the best answer is here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667188/how-to-use-pdofetch-class-with-abstract-class/12667615#12667615?newreg=b8f15b5468f54945b5d287af0c54005b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not know the type (classname) of the returned objects before you do the query, you can not specify it.

However, you could encapsulate that logic inside another type you use as return type which can then return the specific return type:

```
/**
 * Should not have any private, public or protected members in it's definition.
 * 
 * Does only work for public properties.
 */
class ReturnObject {
    public function getConcrete()
    {
        /* decide here which class */
       $classname = 'Child'; // or 'Adult'

       return $this->selfAs($classname);
    }

    private function selfAs($classname)
    {
        $l = strlen(__CLASS__);
        $s = sprintf('O:%d:"%s"', strlen($classname), $classname).substr(serialize($this), 5+strlen($l)+$l);
        $instance = unserialize($s);
        $instance->__construct();
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

You can then use the `getConcrete()` function on each returned object to return your specific type, your decision logic bound to the database return.

**Edit:** I changed it into a version that will first initialize the objects properties via unserialize (please test if this works, it's based on the assumption that we're talking about public properties only and I don't know if PDO just does the setters or more via reflection in the mode you're using) and then calls the constructor function. The constructor needs to be public (and it must exist) so that this works.

It's technically possible to make this available for private and protected members as well, however this needs real reflection and it as well needs parsing of the serialized data as well. This class only renames the classname, but not inside private properties.

However this is only one way for doing so. You probably only need a `->isChild()` or `->isAdult()` function on your `Person` class.

Comment: As I am not using PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE the constructor is called after the properties are set. Can I achieve this with your code?

Comment: @Ghommey: I updated the answer. I don't know your specific needs, this outlines at least how you can control when the constructor is called, but it works for public properties only so far. No idea if that is your need. If you need to support more, please give feedback. And please test if that runs, have nothing to play for PDO here.

Comment: Thanks hakre I will definitely test this tomorrow and would upvote you a second time if I could.

Answer (score 0):

This cant really be done automaticly, it is too specific. You can just loop over each row and instantiate the correct class with the proper arguments.

Comment: So how can I access the row value and turn it into a class the same way as PDO::FETCH_CLASS does?

Comment: Just create method that will create decorator instance for you that will wrap original class and extend it. Than you can run this method on each item in collection and retrieve correct child class.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use PDO::FETCH_CLASS for that.
You can change your SQL to return class name based on value of age

```
SELECT 
id,
name,
age,
CASE WHEN age < 21 THEN 'child'
ELSE 'adult' END
AS class_name
FROM SOME_TABLE";

Then use your PDO::FETCH_ASSOC as fetch type
Then when you loop over your results
you can easily instantiave class based on
$result['class_name'] like this:
$class = $result['class_name'];
$obj = new $class;
```

Comment: In PDO::FETCH_CLASS the constructor is called after the values are set. How would I achieve this with your example?

Comment: I said, do not use PDO::FETCH_CLASS. Just do a normal select then loop over results and then instantiate your class based on class_name. PDO::FETCH_CLASS while looks like a cool way to magically get object back from DB in reality is not good at all - not efficient, requires the properties to be public or to have magic __set($name, $val) methods.

Comment: Right but how can I set the values BEFORE it calls the constructor?

Comment: You can pass your values to the constructor. Just rewrite your constructor to accept values like age, name and you can pass these
$obj = new $class($result['name'], $result['age'])

Comment: I can't rewrite the constructors. I want to set the properties BEFORE the constructor is called. Just the same way as PDO::FETCH_CLASS would do it.

Comment: Why can't you change constructor? It's unusual to have properties set before constructor is called, I would say it's beyond highly unusual. The fact that PDO::FETCH_CLASS sets values before calling constructor is more of a side-effect than a feature. You should not rely on it.
Also you can call your $obj->__construct(); manually after you set your variables as a last resort, also very unusual way to do things

Comment: We are trying to fix a bug and therefore have to change existing open source code. I don't care whether it is unusual or a side effect. I have to implement it the same way as FETCH_CLASS would do.

Answer (score 0):

I think wich the best answer is here.

[How to use PDO::FETCH_CLASS with abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667188/how-to-use-pdofetch-class-with-abstract-class/12667615#12667615?newreg=b8f15b5468f54945b5d287af0c54005b)