# How to dynamically instantiate an object in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, object, dynamic

Can we dynamically create and initialize an object in PHP?
This is the normal code:

```
class MyClass{
    var $var1 = null;
    var $var2 = null;
    .
    .
    public function __construct($args){
        foreach($args as $key => $value)
            $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
---------------------
$args = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") ? $_POST : $_REQUEST;
$obj = new MyClass($args);
```

The above code works fine. Please note that the names of **REQUEST** parameters are accurately mapped with the members of class **MyClass**.

But can we do something like this:

```
$class = "MyClass";
$obj = new $class;
```

If we can do like this, then can we initialize **$obj** by using **$args**.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201335/dynamically-create-php-object-based-on-string), **$obj = $class** should work. But it does not work for me. I tried **get_class_vars($obj)**. It threw an exception.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question / problem? Please post the code that does not work for you.

Comment: Possible related: [PDO::FETCH_CLASS with multiple classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7741590/367456)

Comment: That question is about dynamically instantiating objects as well (apart from PDO which made it more complicated for the person asking) and you *might* find some useful stuff about populating the new objects in the various answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to overload some other [magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members):

- __get (a method that gets called when you call object member)
- __set (a method that gets called when you want to set object member)
- __isset
- __unset

Please see this [codepad](http://codepad.org/eM9ezgkp) to see your code rewritten to work with what you want:

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    var $properties = array();

    public function __construct($args){
        $this->properties = $args;        
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        echo "Getting '$name'\n";
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->properties)) {
            return $this->properties[$name];
        }
        return null;
    } 
}

$args = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
$class = "MyClass";
$obj = new $class($args);
echo "key1:". $obj->key1;
?>
```

Comment: Or alternatively extend the concrete classes from `ArrayObject` and set some flags.

Answer (score 12):

It's more a comment, but I leave it here more prominently:

```
$class = "MyClass";
$obj = new $class($args);
```

This does work. See [`new`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/new).

Answer (score 10):

You can use Reflection to instanciate an object with parameters.

```
<?php

class Foo {
    protected $_foo;
    protected $_bar;

    public function __construct($foo, $bar)
    {
        $this->_foo = $foo;
        $this->_bar = $bar;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        echo $this->_foo . ' ' . $this->_bar . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$objectClass = 'Foo';
$args = array('Hello', 'World');

$objectReflection = new ReflectionClass($objectClass);
$object = $objectReflection->newInstanceArgs($args);

$object->run();
```

See [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) on php manual.

Comment: Guery: In the link that you provided, in the line, **$a = new A();**, we have to explicitly specify the class name **A**. But what I want is to initialize the object from a class whose named will be based on some query string parameter. You can assume like I have to pass name of the class from the form. Since there are over 30 class, I prefer not using IF-ELSE or SWITCH-BREAK.

Comment: I don't get your point, the above code will instantiate an `$object` based on the $objectClass. In all cases your class need to exists. I edited my answer with a more complete example.