# Namespaces + Framework + Composer

Tags: php

I have read a lot of threads, and PLEASE, just remain to what the question is, probably sounds like a duplicated entry, but sincerely, I've not understand them correctly, so I am looking forward for a reasonable explanation.

I am recreating a Framework (not to be implemented, just to learn how Frameworks work). Structure looks like this:

```
App
App/Core
App/Core/Controllers
App/Core/Controllers/Home
App/Core/Models
App/Core/Views
App/Libraries
App/Libraries/vendor
App/Libraries/composer.json
App/init.php
index.php
.htaccess
```

this is my composer.json file

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "App"
        }
    }
}
```

this is my index.php file

```
const CONTROLLERS = 'App/Core/Controllers/';
require_once 'App/init.php';
$time = microtime(true);
new App\Init();
```

this is my init.php class

```
namespace App;

require_once __DIR__ . '/Libraries/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Controller;

class Init
{

    private $resource;
    private $object;
    private $file;

    const HOME = 'home';

    function __construct()
    {

        $this->resource = empty($_GET) ? array(self::HOME) : self::Uri($_GET['resource']);

        $class = self::Object($this->resource);

        new App\Controller\$class;

    }

    private function Uri($_resource)
    {

        if($_resource != ucfirst(self::HOME))
        {
            $this->resource = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_resource, '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }

        return $this->resource;

    }

    private function Object($_resource)
    {
        $this->object = ucfirst($_resource[0]);
        $this->file =  CONTROLLERS . $this->object . '.php';
        if(file_exists($this->file))
        {
            require $this->file;

            return $this->object;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Nope';
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Home.php class

```
namespace App\Controller;

class Home
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo '<br>I am at home';
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$class' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Please please help me out here, driving me crazy trying to understand why if I use new App\Controller\Home; it works, but if I use $class it crashes. I even tried new App\Controller{$class} with no luck.

Anyway hoping to get an answer a clear answer, because probably a lot of people would go through the same issue

Thank you all in advance

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7952031/1255289

Comment: @miken32 I already went through that post, no answer available. Maybe I missed it, can you please point the answer out?

Comment: `App\Controller\{$class} ` ?

Comment: @Cid I got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: By the way, why using a `new ...` without affectation?

Comment: @Cid affectation? please explain, not sure what you mean about it

Comment: Why writting `new App\Controller\$class;` instead of `$someVar = new App\Controller\$class;` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181169/discussion-between-jorge-and-cid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct your variable variable before using it:

```
$controller = "App\\Controller\\{$class}";
new $controller();
```

Comment: no luck, I got: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Controller\{Home}' not found

Comment: Sorry, needed escaped backslashes, updated

Comment: You did the trick, should I use something like DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR like str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class); ?

Comment: No, that's for filesystem paths :)