# How to use PDO::FETCH_CLASS with abstract class?

Tags: php, pdo

Is there a method to instantiate a child class with `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` based on retrieved data? Suppose that there exists an abstract class `A`, classes `B` and `C` that are implementations of `A` and a field on my table named `classname` that will be used to instantiate the right class. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need, `PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE`. [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> PDO::FETCH_CLASS: returns a new instance of the requested class,
>   mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the
>   class. If fetch_style includes PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE (e.g.
>   PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE) then the name of the class is
>   determined from a value of the first column.

Comment: Is the correct answer, though not solve my problem, since I can not pass arguments to the constructor. I'll have to use a workaround.

Comment: Maybe [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53394) is related, in theory you could make the `__construct` be called before properties being set with `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`